# data stream python subprocess.check_output exe from another location

Tags: python, mono, directory, subprocess

I would like to run an exe from this directory:/home/pi/pi_sensors-master/bin/Release/ 
This exe is then run by tying mono i2c.exe and it runs fine.

I would like to get this output in python which is in a completely different directory.

I know that I should use subprocess.check_output to take the output as a string.

I tried to implement this in python:

```
import subprocess
import os


cmd = "/home/pi/pi_sensors-master/bin/Release/"
os.chdir(cmd)
process=subprocess.check_output(['mono i2c.exe'])
print process
```

However, I received this error:
[image]

The output would usually be a data stream with a new number each time, is it possible to capture this output and store it as a constantly changing variable?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does `sudo mono i2c.exe` from the terminal work?

Comment: here is the output from terminal: http://prntscr.com/3xy211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command syntax is incorrect, which is actually generating the exception. You want to call `mono i2c.exe`, so your command list should look like:

```
subprocess.check_output(['mono', 'i2c.exe']) # Notice the comma separation.
```

Try the following:

```
import subprocess
import os

executable = "/home/pi/pi_sensors-master/bin/Release/i2c.exe"

print subprocess.check_output(['mono', executable])
```

The `sudo` is not a problem as long as you give the full path to the file and you are sure that running the `mono` command as `sudo` works.

I can generate the same error by doing a `ls -l`:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['ls -l'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However when you separate the command from the options:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l'])
# outputs my entire folder contents which are quite large.
```

---

I strongly advice you to use the [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) -object to deal with external processes. Use [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to get the data from both `stdout` and `stderr`. This way you should not run into blocking problems.

```
import os
import subprocess

executable = "/home/pi/pi_sensors-master/bin/Release/i2c.exe"
proc = subprocess.Popen(['mono', executable])

try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15) # Times out after 15 seconds.
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
```

Or you can call the communicate in a loop if you want a 'data-stream' of sort, [an answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/python-read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

executable = "/home/pi/pi_sensors-master/bin/Release/i2c.exe"
p = Popen(["mono", executable], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line,
p.communicate() # close p.stdout, wait for the subprocess to exit
```

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately nothing is being output

Comment: I have no idea what `mono` is doing, but if it's some sort of a service which does not exit, then I assume `check_output()` will block.

Comment: yes it does not exit it keeps outputting stuff, is it possible to take a stream of this output as a constantly changing variable?\

Comment: @Hamoudy check my edit. You should be able to achieve what you want with `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: it is strange that when I run the data stream, i get the first three lines and then stops: http://prntscr.com/3xy8sg

Comment: do you think the buffer might be full?

Comment: Yeah `communicate()` expects an EOF and you're apparently streaming data. I've edited the answer again, see if that works. I also found another question similar to yours from which I adapted the example.

Comment: Then you'll have to investigate further, the data stream is probably not what I expect. Try looking at the other answers in the question I linked.

Comment: I restarted my pi and it just worked, is it possible to remove the new line?

Comment: Yeah, just add a comma after the print statement in the loop. Edited in the example now. `print line,`